# 貸してもいいですか versus 借りてもいいですか

Tags: grammar, nuances

According to my teacher who is a native Japanese, the second option cannot be used even though it is grammatically correct. What do you think? Any comments are appreciated.

## Option 1

> 彼：すみません。消しゴムを忘れたので、「私があなたに」消しゴムを借りてもいいですか。
>
> 彼女：ええ。どうぞ。

## Option 2

> 彼：すみません。消しゴムを忘れたので、「あなたが私に」消しゴムを貸してもいいですか。
>
> 彼女：ええ。どうぞ。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 消しゴムを忘れたので、（あなたが私に）消しゴムを貸してもいいですか。

This sounds strange. You use ～てもいいですか for asking for permission (= 'May I ~~?'), so '（私があなたに・あなたから）・・・借りてもいいですか' is correct. If you want to use the verb 貸す, here 貸す is the action done by the listener, not the speaker, so you would rather say

> 消しゴムを忘れたので、（あなたが私に）消しゴムを貸してくれませんか。

You use ～てくれませんか for requesting/asking someone to do something (= 'Could you ~~?')

You can also say

> 消しゴムを忘れたので、（私があなたに）消しゴムを貸してもらえませんか。

Here the subject would be 私 because the subject of 貸す is the listener but the subject of 貸してもらう is the speaker.

Comment: Is 貸してもらっていいですか less polite, you think?

Comment: How about the following:

彼：すみません。消しゴムを忘れた。
彼女：貸してもいいですか。
彼：はい。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @FriendlyGhost You'd say 貸しましょうか or 貸してあげましょうか (for making an offer)

Comment: 分かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @ssb 貸してもらって**も**いいですか would be fine (the subject would be 私, though), and yeah it sounds a little bit less polite to me.

Comment: You can also use 貸してもらえますか。/ 貸してもらえませんか。/ 貸していただけませんか。 etc...